# Transaction resolution using Intel SGX

Tags: corda, sgx

According to this post from Mike Hearn:

https://www.corda.net/2017/06/corda-sgx-privacy-update/

in the transaction resolution process, I understand that in a transaction between a proposer A and party B:

1. Proposer A sends the transaction to Party B
2. Party B needs the transaction chain to validate the transaction, so asks for it (the transaction history) to Party A
3. After the enclave and secure channel established, enclave on Party A sends the transaction history encrypted to the enclave on Party B
4. Enclave on Party B decrypts it and validates the transaction

From now, suppose Party B is the proposer for a new transaction with Party C, using the UTXO from the previous transaction.
As Party C will need all transaction history, how does it work? In the previous transaction, once it is validated, is the transaction chain stored encrypted on Party B (for subsequent transactions)?

If it's not clear, please, let me know to try to explain better the scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the resolved transaction chain is stored in encrypted form on Party B's node. This is for two reasons:
1. Party B may need it for future transaction resolutions - otherwise it would have to download a ton of stuff again
2. Party B may need to present the chain to Party C later on, as you suggest

Does this mean that every node has to run SGX? In our initial design, yes. But in the future we may investigate how an enclave can convince a non-SGX node that a transaction chain is legit.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Joel's answer, it's possible to use SGX in two different ways: one that prioritises privacy and one that prioritises integrity. We're thinking that production networks where obtaining SGX hardware is no problem (cloud support is on the way) will prefer integrity and thus verify all transactions in the chain inside the enclave. This is what we're implementing first.

But we can also support "light mode clients" where remote attestation is used to just give a statement that a tx was valid, and in this case you don't need to run an enclave yourself. E.g. mobile phones could use this mode. This would yield something conceptually similar to Bitcoin's SPV mode, but with different security properties: if you can mine a block you can fool SPV clients into believing something is valid when it's not if you can also partition it from the network, but to do the same with an SGX based lightweight mode you'd need to beat the enclave security.